# split and merge 2 files into two in bash

Tags: bash, file, input, output

So I have this problem where I need to merge 2 images with another into 1 file (first byte of pic 1, first byte of pic 2, second byte of pic 1, second byte of pic 2 etc')
how do I merge them(in bash) and how do I split them?
Let's say the names of the files are 1.png and 2.png
and the merge file is merge.png

Comment: Would this work for you: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/layers/ ?

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their existing programming code. Edit your Q to show sample inputs/outputs and your best attempt at coding a solution to your problem. Sorry, but requests for tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, libraries, and code are off-topic.  ***Please*** read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck